# Name input field showing credit card autofill suggestions in latest chrome

Tags: html, angular, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill

In my angular app on just one page one of the input field(which is for name) showing credit card suggestions and if I disable the autofill for credit card in chrome settings then it shows suggestions for name.But why it shows suggestions for credit card even I had same input field with same attributes on other page but there I only got name suggestions.

Comment: It's not the issue with `Angular` or `HTML`. It's because of some settings in `Google Chrome`. Once open in `Incognito window` and try.

Comment: Right.so is there any solution to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution.
Just add `autocomplete="name"` attribute to the input field and explicitly tell chrome that treat this input field for Name.
reference [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/forms/)